# C++ Programming tools

Tags: c++

My teacher recommended us to use notepad++ and cygwin for our programming needs. Are there any better solutions anyone can recommend out there to program  and compile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Myriad of various IDE's.... Eclipse CDT, Visual Studio Express, Code::Blocks, DevCPP....

And yes, Notepad++ and Cygwin with gcc would be a very viable option if you only need to compile single files for your homework.

Comment: I think i might try out Visual Studio one of these days

Comment: I would strongly advice against DevCpp, unless you want IDE you will need to debug. :P It is not supported now and should be banned; I don't know why it is still so popular, when there is Code::Blocks.

Answer (score 6):

Use a IDE

> An integrated development environment (IDE) (also known as integrated design environment, integrated debugging environment or interactive development environment) is a software application that provides comprehensive facilities to computer programmers for software development. An IDE normally consists of:
>   a source code editor
>   a compiler and/or an interpreter
>   build automation tools
>   a debugger

A few of them to choose from

http://netbeans.org/index.html

http://www.codeblocks.org/

http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, a very important tool for beginners is a debugger. A lot of question can be answered by yourself if you have a look into the debugger. You can use the gdb but it is hard to use and understand for beginners. So I would recommend to use Visual C++ 2010 Express which has an excellent and easy to use debugger.

Comment: A lot of teachers want there students to learn the basic stuff first. But what are the basics today? Arrays, pointers, <cstring>, g++ command line usage? Like std::string, std::vector and modern C++ concepts, a debugger is one of the first tools a new C++ programmer should learn to use, from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer**:

> The following are personal opinions, related to my personal taste on
>   the subject. Anyone in the programmer community has its own taste and
>   preferences an can agree or not. Here I just want to tell you about
>   some rationals. Consider products and related names as "examples."

**My Answer**
There are mainly three ways to write code:

- The manual one
- The assisted one
- The automated one.

Think to them as:

- Driving your car alone
- Driving with a navigator
- Driving with an autopilot.

Here "driving alone" means "use a generic text editor, a command-line based compiler and a command-line based debugger. The editor may eventually have a clue about the language syntax (thus differentiating different language structural elements, like keyword, literals, operators etc.) but knowing really nothing about *what* you are coding.
This is what notepad++ does. It makes coding harder, but for very simple things makes you really learn how to "drive".

A "navigator" is a basic IDE like Devc++, or like CodeBlocks: they have the notion of "project", manage the relation between files and manage the invocation of the compiler and debugger, managing the mapping on their output respect to your sources.
You write your own code, but the "road to compile" is told by the "navigator" you have to trust.

An "autopilot" is a more complex IDE (like VisualStudio, Netbeans, Eclipse ...) that can also "manage the code" providing code analysis *for either syntax and semantics*, context sensitive auto-completion, code generation for common tasks.
They can give you some code you have to complete and connect together.
They make you faster in producing code, testing it, debugging it, but you must have more trust in them or know how they "suggest". 
They can be productive, but you have to "configure" them to suite your needs.

Now: since everything is a matter of "*trust*", and you *cannot trust what you don't know yet*, and is a matter of "knowing yuur needs" (but a learner may not yet have an idea abut them)

- starting with "beasts" like VisualStudio (that mess arout 50% of your computer  registry, pretend you to download GIGABYTES from the Internet and installs GIGABYTES of whatever MS library) is clueless: before you will start using all of that, will take years, and VS itself will be changed 2 or three times) or Eclipse (that has the more powerful syntax and semantic analizer, but requires lot of "arcane configuration" you don't even know since you didn't make the first step in programming) may be an excess. At least until your programs will stay in a couple of pages.
- starting win notepad++ and GCC (or Mingw) is just a matter of dowload few megabytes, set a PATH, and you go. Fastest way to turn the key on.
- when things become more complex, and require some help in organize them, simple IDE like CodeBloks or Codelite are more than effective at "to the point". I will avoid Dev-C++: it's OLD, and doesn't support the "state of art of the C++ language". You an live with them for all your scolarity
- when going to more professional kind of projects, and your experience in "using tools" is better, things like Eclipse, or NetBeans may become more "effective". I will in any case avoid VisualStudio: it's not that "effective". But it is the best to develop in Microsoft environments producing MS oriented applications, especially in the ".Net" world. Something you will not see before 2/3 years of experience.

Comment: In my opinion (and maybe update since this answer was posted) you need the power of a fully fledged dev environment such as Visual Studio to have the tooling ready for importing packages, deploying stuff, devops.

Comment: @real_yggdrasil: At a professional level it may make sense. But I doubt that someone who ask a question beginning with "my teacher" will have to do with any of those stuffs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're learning you can download VStudio Express. I believe it's free. Easier to use than notepad and cygwin. This isn't a biased opinion. I'm a Linux C++ developer most days but acknowledge the fact that it might be easier to learn using VStudio.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux, you can use kate and g++ for editing and compiling c++ files.

If you are using windows, I think your teacher's recommendations are good. Althought there are various IDE's for C++, it is better to use a simple editor that doesn't have code completion and compilation feature while learning a programming language for the first time. IDE's are nice but not good for learners I think.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a good idea to go with your teacher's suggestion, since you might also need some help in the future, either from him or your colleagues. Another advantage is that, being in school, you'll probably develop using more than one programming language. Notepad++ has support for almost everything you can think of, so you can use it not only for this course. That way you'll have an advantage because you'll learn shortcuts, etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on doing a lot of programming in the future, I highly recommend putting the effort into learning [VIM](http://www.vim.org/). Nothing else can touch it in terms of speed and power. It has built-in shell access and it is programmable. It is like having God in your text editor. The major down-side is the steep learning curve.

Also, you want to use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) in-case you screw-up and want to go back to a previous point. It lets you periodically check-point your code so you can always go back. For example, maybe you delete something, then later on decide you want to use that code after all. If you've been check-pointing with Git, you can get it back.

[Graphical differs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/792910/336892) sometimes come in handy too.

Answer (score 0):

I started coding in C++ using Turbo C++(the default program available on college computers, I told them it was prehistoric), but then I found Visual Studio Express and never looked back since that day.

Also since i could not install Visual Studio on College computers, I put a portable version of DevC++ on my pen drive to use there.

Eventually I got the College to install Visual Studio Express editions on all Lab Computers (Once I managed to convince them that it was free with no Licensing issues)

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner, go with a text editor and a compiler. Helps you in understanding what *actually* goes on.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Dev-C++, which is a good compiler for C and C++, if you want lightweight.
Otherwise Visual Studio probably.

Comment: It's 2011: DevC++ last activity was before 2005, with compiler that even don't have a standard support for C++2003!

It's very popular becouse of its long history, but don't suggest to new students you rusty (and buggy) tools!